# How to Truly Permanently enable Flash for All Sites on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

On the latest Chrome versions, google has edited the flash settings to 2
Default (ask) to use Flash
or
Block all Sites from using Flash
and this frustrates me alot, having to whitelist every site with flash (I visit many every day) and I was wondering if someone could help me
Yes Ive tried the
Chrome://Flags
 Enable Ephemeral Flash use
thing. but they removed it in the latest update, so you cant permanently enable flash, and no I don't want to have to whitelist every site I use and write it in settings, that would take ages, and I visit new sites almost every day.

Answer (score -1):

You can't enable Flash permanently in Chrome. This is not a bug. Chrome deliberately removed this feature.